# Calling a certain class/ID

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a shopping cart, and it once an item is added a trash icon appears. There is a current script that works but it targets all of the 'onclick' functions in the page. I would just like it to target this one (garbage can one). Here is the code for the icon.

```
<td class="total">
  <span class="close" style="color:#f00;">
    <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
  </span>
</td>
```

Now the current JavaScript is like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

$('body').on('click','.close', function(){
var here = $(this);
var rowid = here.closest('tr').data('rowid');
```

Theres more JavaScript although I'm just showing the beginning.

I tried something like this, but nothing worked.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var trash = document.getElementsByClassName("fa fa-trash");
  trash.on('click', '.close', function(){
  var here = $(this);
```

I don't know if I am on the right track.

Comment: You're mixing jQuery and pure JS in a very odd way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, you just want to bind the `click` event to the trash icons?

If so..

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('body').on('click','.fa.fa-trash', function(){
   var here = $(this);  //This variable now equals the clicked trash element.
   var rowid = here.closest('tr').data('rowid');
```

Furthermore, it's best practice to use a `$` sign on the front of the variable when it contains a jQuery element.  That way you and anyone else reading the code can distinguish between the elements and know which variables can have jQuery methods executed upon.

```
var $here = $(this);
```

Comment: Thank you!! It works. So basically to understand this for the future. $('body') gets all of the body elements and on( click) it will call the .fa fa-trash class?

Comment: Not really.  `$(body)` references the DOM contained in your html `body` tag.  The jQuery method `.on` attaches to the `body` and listens for `click` on the class elements you've specified. Doing it this way, insures any dynamically added elements are also included in the `click` event.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
var trash = document.getElementsByClassName("fa fa-trash");
```

with

```
var trash = $(".fa.fa-trash");
```

If you want to use `JS` to fetch the elements, using `document.getElementsByClassName` then you will have to iterate over a for loop and bind the events specifically for each.

```
  var trashes = document.getElementsByClassName("fa fa-trash");
  for(var i=0; i< trashes.length; i++) {
     var $trash = trashes[i];

     $trash.on('click', '.close', function() {

    ...
  } // end of for loop
```

Use `querySelectorAll`

```
 var trash = document.querySelectorAll(".fa.fa-trash");
  trash.on('click', ...
```

Comment: Still nothing, it doesn't remove my item when I click it.

Comment: @Jeff, thats not what you asked for, and you didn't show any of that code.  Sushanth provided a very good answer to your question